# Network Question - gnupg

Tags: networking, gnupg, keyserver

I am trying to understand what is happening with my network.  I am logging in to the wireless with a low priv user.  However after logging in, I see the following.  In my root/  a folder is created and keys are added from keyservers.  One keyserver looks like ubuntu the other is something else.  Is this a backdoor?

```
root     27448   745  0 13:26 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /var/run/dhclient-eth1.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-38acbc8b-bd75-44f4-9ec5-d6a712934954-eth1.lease -cf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-eth1.conf eth1
root     27558     1  0 13:26 ?        00:00:00 gpg-agent --homedir /root/.gnupg --use-standard-socket --daemon
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas for editing post.   It also creates gpg-agent socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, let's address the processes.  These're two unrelated processes.

Firstly, `dhclient` is being used alongside NetworkManager on your system to get the IP address dynamically for `eth1` connections.  That's not a keyserver.

Secondly, `gpg-agent` tends to be started on desktop instances when you logon via a GUI, to handle GPG requests for decryption, encryption, signatures, etc. within the GUI.  This way, you get nice GUI prompts from GPG for your password instead of other prompts.

What's missing here is that you don't tell us if you enabled the root user or anything. If you did, and you don't have `sudo` privs on any other users and you use separate permissions and such, then you *could* have been breached.  But usually, `gpg-agent` isn't a backdoor, it's only listening locally.  (Any launch of gpg-agent though can open such a command though, in this case it's on the root user so *someone* may have logged in as `root` via the GUI).

---

As to whether this is a backdoor or a breach, we can't reliably answer that without direct inspection of the system, network traffic, etc.  It's not able to be determined solely from what is stated here whether it's a breach or not.

Comment: Ok, clear on the dhclient.  From guestish user, it issues an connect request.  Root takes over and does what it needs to do by starting dhclient.

Comment: I didn't enable the root user. via logging in to it.   TCPDUMP, netstat, don't indicate anything right now.   But thanks, this is not a common technique by hackers.  I was thinking maybe it was downloading some keys to begin its mischief.